# plusses/minuses of a modern pellet boiler system?

Tags: heating, central-heating

I know someone who is considering one of the Okofen (or equivalent) pellet-fuel systems to replace his house's dying oil-fired boiler. (He's keeping the existing Forced Hot Water baseboard system to distribute the heat.)

Looking at this, it appears that pellet systems are now sufficiently self feeding and self cleaning to address some of my own concerns, which were based on not having seen pellet stoves used for anything much larger than a workshop.

I'd like to see some comments from folks who have such a system on what is good, bad, unexpected, or just plain different about it compared to the usual alternative fuels of oil and gas.

Comment: Wander over to hearth.com

Comment: Thanks, @ecnerwal; that did provide many of the answers we were looking for. Unfortunately it isn't an answer by SE's standards.

Comment: No kidding, I posted it as a comment, not an answer. Little point in rehashing it all "here" when "there" is a far better established resource for that particular line of inquiry. I've gone back and forth on getting one, and that is bar none the best site on the internet I've found about that and related subjects. Does not happen to be a SE site, I don't happen to care about that. If some SE person with a boiler wants to post an answer, have at it - but it will be a single pellet .vs. a few tons of them by comparison...

Comment: So how do I close this out as answered-indirectly? Just delete it?

Comment: Leave it open and see what develops, or delete, as you prefer. I'd say leave it open, personally.